# Using SELECT to retrieve data from Access Database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a "SELECT" query in Excel using VBA.

```vb
CommodityInfo = ObjAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute( _
"SELECT TOP 1 Commodity FROM [" & CustomerName & "]")
```

It works. I'm struggling with using the information in the `CommodityInfo` variable. I can see in my Locals window that the information is there. How do I use it to output the value?
[image: Item 1]

Item 1 is clearly displayed so its being accessed. How do I pull out the value from item 1 and use it as I would a string?
[image]

`Count` can be used by stating `CommodityInfo.Count`.
I tried `ComVal = CommodityInfo(1).Value` but I get the error

> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

Comment: try CommodityInfo = ObjAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute( _
"SELECT TOP 1 Commodity FROM [" & CustomerName & "]")(0) . I am not sure that your select statement is correct, but CommodityInfo  is recordset and not plain value.

Comment: @xShen Yeah, that seems to pull the value fine alone and not the entire recordset. Why does adding a (0) work this way here? Is it like stating the element to access?

Comment: try CommodityInfo.MoveFirst then ComVal = CommodityInfo["Commodity"]

Comment: the return of CurrentProject.Connection.Execute is an recordset object, not a value , some time there is only one value in the return but steel it is an object   try read more  https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+access+recordset.

Comment: Do you have a table for each customer?

Comment: I do, ```CustomerName``` is a variable that is dependant on user selection that specifies the table from a list of tables in the database.

Comment: Okay, why? Conventional structure would be one table with a field for CustomerID then apply filter criteria in SQL.

Comment: Probably because I didin't think of that when planning... :) But yes a separate line for each entry seems far more plausible.. back to adjusting things..

Comment: @June7 How much of a potential speed deficit would individual tables pose over filtering a single table of entries (not that accessing an access database via VBA isn't already slow)

Comment: I don't know if there would be any difference. However, if you ever need to output a report that includes all customers, the conventional structure should be faster than the alternative of a UNION query. Also, if you have to add customers, the conventional structure is more flexible, not requiring design changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, your code is opening a recordset object, not pulling a single value.

Since field index is zero based, use 0 for first field instead of 1: `ComVal = CommodityInfo(0)` to pull single field value from recordset to simple variable.

Or append Execute command with field index reference to extract single field value directly to simple variable.

```
CommodityInfo = ObjAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute( _
               "SELECT TOP 1 Commodity FROM [" & CustomerName & "]")(0)
```

Here is alternative to pull a single value instead of opening a recordset:
`CommodityInfo = ObjAccess.DLookup("Commodity", "[" & CustomerName & "]")`.
In my test, it ran faster.

It is possible to pull data from Access without instantiating an Access application object variable. I found this code ran fastest.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='your access database filepath'"
CommodityInfo = cn.Execute("SELECT TOP 1 Commodity FROM [" & CustomerName & "]")(0)
```

Or

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
CommodityInfo = cn.Execute("SELECT TOP 1 Commodity FROM [" & CustomerName & "]" IN 'your database filepath'")(0)
```